# Ubuntu 14.04 install hardware enablement stack for kernel beyond 3.13.x?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

I know there are tons of documents online talking about hardware enablement stack, I also know the theory for LTS to get more closer kernel and X library, so does it means I CAN NOT install kernel beyond 3.13.x on 14.04 LTS platform unless I install HWE stack? I am trying to understand in detail of the steps before execute upgrade on production servers. Also, does HWE stack cause conflict on packages or kernel module?

I also tested install kernel using "apt-get install linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic", it render unbootable system and have to rescue by boot into 3.13.x older kernel and remove it, this cause confusion, if I could see on apt-get, should I be able to install new kernel without making my system unbootable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install kernel 3.16 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

or kernel 3.19

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

This will install meta packages and the selected kernel major version will get updates using normal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` routine.

Why did you install an old 3.19.0-18? Current is  `3.19.0-23`.

I use all my Ubuntu 14.04 systems with kernel 3.19 with no problems.

Comment: So in theory I will screw up my system without install linux-generic-lts-vivid but doing apt-get install linux-image-3.19.0-23, is this correct statement? Also, any disadvantage of running HWE for future LTS version upgrade?

Comment: It is not correct, because you do not install `linux-image-extra` and `linux-headers` related. There is no disadvantage if you install it correctly.

Comment: and if I install linux-image-extra, headers and kernel itself, I should be able to boot new kernel without probem?

Comment: If you install the package I suggested all these packages will be installed automatically. That's the whole point of this. Why do you want to install them separately?

Comment: Well, in case I forget :) yes I understand what you mean, thanks.